# Hibernate. Get lazy collection size on jsp

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, lazy-loading, open-session-in-view

I am using `Spring MVC` with `OpenSessionInViewFilter` and trying to find best practice to get lazy collection size on jsp (without loading collection and `LazyInitializationException`).
Any solutions?

Comment: It's a common issu. The solution is the Open Session Pattern
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847040/open-session-in-view-pattern

Answer (score 0):

Either use a dedicated HQL query that counts the elements in the collection, or use [extra-lazy fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching), which can be enabled using the `@LazyCollection` annotation.

Comment: yes, I know about `extra-lazy fetching` and it's works fine in controller but on jsp I still have `LazyInitializationException`

Comment: You shouldn't if you're really using the OpenSessionInView filter.